# What’s the difference between AbstractMessageSource and MessageProducerSupport in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, project-reactor

When developing inbound channel adapters, I couldn’t find any place that mentions the differences between `AbstractMessageSource` and `MessageProducerSupport` in Spring Integration. I’m asking this question in the context of reactive streams, so I’m actually looking at `AbstractReactiveMessageSource`, but I guess it doesn’t matter for my question. I also wonder whether `MessageProducerSupport` supports project reactor and doesn’t have an equivalent to `AbstractReactiveMessageSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some documentation about these types of components: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html#finding-class-names-for-java-and-dsl-configuration

> The inbound message flow side has its own components, which are divided into polling and listening behaviors.

So, the `MessageProducerSupport` is for those protocols which provide a listening callback for us. So, we can hook up into that, build message and produce it into a channel provided by the `MessageProducer`. So, it is  self-eventing component which really has everything to listen to the source system and produce messages from the callback. This type of channel adapters called event-driven and samples of them are JMS, AMQP, HTTP, IMAP,  Kinesis etc.

From here it is wrong to try to compare the `MessageProducerSupport` with an `AbstractMessageSource` because the are not relevant. The one you should look into is a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`. Exactly this one is that kind of flow beginning endpoint which is similar to `MessageProducerSupport`. With only the problem that it is based on a periodic scheduled task to request for messages in the provided `MessageSource`. This type of component is for those protocols which don't provide listening callback, e.g. local file system, (S)FTP, JDBC, MongoDb, POP3, S3 etc.

You probable would expect something similar to `MessageSource` for the `MessageProducer` level, but there is not that kind of layer because everything single event-driven protocol has its own specifics, therefore we cannot extract some common abstraction like in case of polling protocols.

If your source system provides for you a reactive `Publisher`, you don't need to look into a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` and `MessageSource`. You just need a `MessageProducerSupport` and call its `subscribeToPublisher(Publisher<? extends Message<?>> publisher)` from the `start()` implementation.

There is no need in the reactive implementation for the polling since `Publisher` is not pollable by itself it is event-driven. Although it has its own back-pressure specifics which is out of `MessageProducerSupport` scope.

There is also some explanation in  this section of the doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/reactive-streams.html#source-polling-channel-adapter. And see a couple next paragraphs.

Comment: I understand `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`, but you still haven’t explained what is the purpose of `AbstractMessageSource` / `AbstractReactiveMessageSource` and when do we need them.

Comment: There is no reactive message source, so no need to explain . And there is no need in one. The reactive `Publisher` is not pollable it is streaming therefore event-driven.

Comment: The message source is an abstraction to implement for those protocols which returns something only when we call them. For example a SELECT for RDBMS. But to make it close to event-driven and let the data flow through our integration , we can only request it periodically . And that’s where source polling channel adapter is used. It polls message source for data and adapt it to message

Comment: But what’s the difference between `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` and `AbstractMessageSource`?

Comment: You cannot compare them : the source is called from that adapter. There are no any other source polling channel adapters . It is only one and it is supplied with a source to poll at runtime. When you think about some target protocol, you implement a message source if there is no listener callback in their driver. You just use polling channel adapter in the target project with integration flow. Your custom source is injected into that channel adapter in that final project.